# memory access in multi core processors vs multiple cpu's

Tags: multicore, multiprocessor

I have a question,

is it possible for multiple processor machine to access data from RAM ( single ram system ) ? 
for eg machine has 2 processors p1, p2 which are executing in parallel , is it possible that they access same ram for read and write ( ofcos write is not on same location )

i understand that in multi core machines it will not be possible since data bus is shared.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the RAM is mapped to all cores or processors (such as in a multi-threaded application) it may be accessed from any core or processor.

There is no difference if you're discussing single processor/single core, single processor/multi-core, multi-processor/(each with a) single-core or multi-processor/multi-core. Since they have no system RAM of their own - the RAM in caches is not system RAM - the only RAM available to all of them is the system RAM.

The only difference between multi-processor/single core (as in older systems) and single processor/multi-core (modern systems) is that the former needs to coordinate RAM accesses with off-chip logic whereas for the latter all coordination is on-chip and sometimes even on-die which of course results in much faster and more electronically efficient RAM accesses.

In the case of AMD's multi-processor/multi-core solutions each processor owns part of the system RAM. The processors themselves are interconnected with high-speed data (HyperTransport) channels to facilitate accesses to RAM not owned by the processor accessing it.

In any case it is up to the programmer to decide how the processors/cores access the RAM. Sure they can read and/or write to the same location if that is what the programmer wants.